# XML .value() method issue with CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL option

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert rows into comma delimited string. Here is my table and data

```
drop table test
create table test (a int, b int, c varchar(30), d varchar(30))
insert into test values(1,1,'<1>','<d>')
insert into test values(1,1,'<2>','<d>')
insert into test values(1,2,'<3>','<d>')
insert into test values(1,2,'<4>','<d>')
insert into test values(1,3,'<5>','<d>')
insert into test values(1,3,'<6>','<d>')
```

I am expecting a result of

```
, <1> - <d>, <2> - <d>, <3> - <d>, <4> - <d>, <5> - <d>, <6> - <d>
```

If I use

```
select 
(SELECT ',' + ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(tc.c)) +' - '+ ltrim(rtrim(tc.d))
   FROM  test tc
    FOR XML PATH(''),type)
```

the query gives the the following result

```
, &lt;1&gt; - &lt;d&gt;, &lt;2&gt; - &lt;d&gt;, &lt;3&gt; - &lt;d&gt;, &lt;4&gt; - &lt;d&gt;, &lt;5&gt; - &lt;d&gt;, &lt;6&gt; - &lt;d&gt;
```

Therefore I added .value method as follows

```
select 
(SELECT ',' + ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(tc.c)) +' - '+ ltrim(rtrim(tc.d))
   FROM  test tc
    FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
```

This one produces the correct result. Here comes my real issue:
It works only when I set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on. 
If I set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL off Sql Server complains with

```
"Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations."
```

**But I don't want to set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on since it will conflict with my other queries.
Can anyone tell me what is the solution to this issue?**

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
I saw this in SO

```
SELECT @XYList = @XYList + CONVERT(varchar, X) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, Y) + ','
FROM POINTS
```

My requirements is to build a view. Therefore I cannot use a solution using variable.

My final result looks like this.

```
a   b   products
1   1    <1> - <d>, <2> - <d>
1   2    <3> - <d>, <4> - <d>
1   3    <5> - <d>, <6> - <d>
```

produced by the query when CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set to on

```
SELECT  tp.a, tp.b ,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(tc.c)) +' - '+ ltrim(rtrim(tc.d))
                 FROM  test tc
                WHERE tp.a = tc.a
                  AND tp.b = tc.b
                  FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '' ) products
 FROM test tp
GROUP BY tp.a, tp.b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to BOL, XML type value method requires setting concat_null_yields_null on. If I want to set concat_null_yields_null to off I won't be able to use

```
FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
```

So I turn to a not-very-sound solution as a band-aid. I use replace function to replace the 5 basic XML predefined entities. The query looks like this.

```
SELECT  tp.a, tp.b ,
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + ' ' +ltrim(rtrim(tc.c)) +' - '+ ltrim(rtrim(tc.d))
                 FROM  test tc
                WHERE tp.a = tc.a
                  AND tp.b = tc.b
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )
                ,'&quot;','"'),'&amp;','&'),'&apos;',''''),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>') auto_products
 FROM test tp
GROUP BY tp.a, tp.b
```

The above solved my current panic. Any better solutions are still welcome.